# Initialization and ?: operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

This code fails in Visual Studio 2019:

```
// struct D2D1_COLOR_F { float r,g,b,a};

bool x = ...;
D2D1_COLOR_F col = x ? { 0, 0, 0, 1 } : { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

it also fails in g++ as I tried. Is this a compiler limitation or I'm missing something in the syntax?

Without `?:` it works:

```
if (x)
   col = {0,0,0,1};
else
   col = {1,1,1,1};
```

It works also by explicitly using the constructor:

```
D2D1_COLOR_F col = x ? D2D1_COLOR_F{ 0, 0, 0, 1 } : D2D1_COLOR_F{ 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

It shows syntax errors:

```
1>(20,25): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
1>(20,25): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>(20,38): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
1>(20,40): error C2059: syntax error: ':'
1>(22,9): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '-='
1>(22,9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: It would work with [D2D1_COLOR_F col = x ? D2D1_COLOR_F{ 0, 0, 0, 1 } : D2D1_COLOR_F{ 1, 1, 1, 1 };](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f60b062f8839f4a)

Comment: @Scheff yes, but why wouldn't it work as I coded it?

Comment: A conditional expression doesn't have to be assigned anywhere `cond ? e1 : e2;` - so its type is always determined from the operands alone. What is the type of the operands in your case?

Comment: Because the `?:` has to determine types of 2nd and 3rd arg. but fails? I'm not fully sure. Just noticed that sometimes initializers work and sometimes not but have not yet found out reason for this...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica all right if the type can't be deduced, but in my particular example, the type can be deduced.It doesn't fail because of that. It shows weird errors - I edited.

Comment: No it can't. C++ doesn't make a thousand and one special cases. The type is determined from the second and third operands alone. *Always*.

Comment: I'm afraid your exposed errors don't match the exposed snippet...

Comment: Here is what g++ has to complain about this: [g++ errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1330489eba83f809)

Comment: Anyway, the C++ standard enforces it by grammar. The two operands must be expressions, and a `{ ... }` is not grammatically an expression. The error is a QoI issue. GCC and MSVC inform that the parse failed (not an expression encountered). Clang is more informative https://wandbox.org/permlink/G5zQpS2onSmHqnH0